# split 64 bit loop to several 32 bit loops on integers

Tags: c++, c, loops

Instead of using one 64bit `long` type variable as loop counter, i would rather have several 32bit loop counters. I need longer loops than 32bits can hold, and using 64bits it is slower in my case.

Any ideas how to achieve this, simple ?

Comment: What CPU, compiler, language ? FWIW you can use two nested loops, of course.

Comment: what is the architecture you are using? Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243444/is-it-better-to-use-integers-as-loop-counter-variables?rq=1).

Comment: it is tagged c/c++; it is for cpu/gpu; if you can read, i am fine with idea, not necessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your desired loop count `c` can be divided into two factors that both fit in 32bit integers, then the following will loop `m * n = c` iterations using 32 bit counters. If `c` is a prime for example, this won't work.

```
uint32_t m, n; // initialize according to your needs
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    for(uint32_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {

    }
}
```

Here is a bit more elaborate solution that should work with any loop count. You don't need to factorize the number by hand either. Do note however, that if your loop count is not compile time constant, then any time gained by 32bit counters is surely lost to the 64bit division. If you don't trust that your compiler would substitute `n` and `r` with constant values, then do the calculation by hand.

```
const uint64_t c = 12000000000ull;
const uint32_t m = std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max();

const uint32_t n = c / m;
const uint32_t r = c % m;

for(std::uint32_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for(std::uint32_t j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        do_stuff();
    }
}
for(std::uint32_t i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
    do_stuff();
}
```

Comment: how do we loop it from 0 to 12000000000 ?

Comment: @user3314134 Use the magic of maths to divide it into two factors.

Comment: @user3314134, hmm, that number is easy, but it made me realize that this method doesn't work if you want to loop count that is a prime.

Comment: @user3314134 Have the outer loop go 1000 times, and the inner loop go 12000000 times.

Comment: @user3314134, I added some code to support any 64bit loop count and also the code to calculate the counter limits.

Comment: looks good. if it works, it is the thing i was looking for.

Comment: works just fine. on gpu hardware im not allowed to use std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() but thats fine. thanks again !